# Querying a table that has column names with spaces?

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently trying to get table data that have column names with spaces.

The client has created the database with column names having spaces, the table is joined across other tables, I have tried using the column name in [] and '' but don't seem to work. My query is as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT appliances.*, location.* FROM (appliances LEFT JOIN location ON appliances.Location ID = location.ID) WHERE Location ID = 11";
```

Comment: Don't use spaces. And, if you do, note that `[]` is an M$SQL construct. MySQL uses backticks (`)

Comment: agreed ^ - however, try wrapping both `Location ID` in ticks `\`` that should do it. or rename your column to `Location_ID` using an underscore (a better solution), NOT a hyphen. MySQL will think you want to do math and you will have to use ticks.

Comment: so, where are we with this? 15 mins into this, nothing. Or, have you tried something from comments and not getting results? Do you need a visual answer?

Comment: I asked the client to change the column to have an underscore but this column is linked across many tables in there database.

I have tried the above using backticks but this seems to not work either.

Comment: I posted a visual representation below, it was easier. Try that and if it doesn't work, I will have to delete my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I asked the client to change the column to have an underscore but this column is linked across many tables in there database."*

Since the column name cannot be changed as outlined in comments, give this a try.

```
appliances.`Location ID` = location.ID) WHERE `Location ID`
```

or

```
`appliances`.`Location ID` = location.ID) WHERE `Location ID`
```

- Notice those are ticks and not regular single quotes.

Check for errors also. I do not know which API is being used to connect with, nor on which platform.

- This (example) answer is based on MySQL and not MSSQL, since the question was tagged as mysql.

Comment: @Craig That's great Craig and you're quite welcome. I'm glad to hear that this matter was resolved, *cheers*